# Jboss7 EAP : UT010009: Servlet remoting of type class org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet does not implement javax.servlet.Servlet

Tags: java, spring, maven, servlets, jboss

I try to deploy my War on Jboss7 EAP, but i've this message error : UT010009: Servlet remoting of type class org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet does not implement javax.servlet.Servlet.

15:04:14,541 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./myproject.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./myproject.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: Failed to start service
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UT010009: Servlet remoting of type class org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet does not implement javax.servlet.Servlet
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.ServletInfo.(ServletInfo.java:98)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.createServletConfig(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:731)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.start(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:283)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
        ... 3 more

15:04:14,544 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 91) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "myproject.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./myproject.UndertowDeploymentInfoService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./myproject.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: Failed to start service
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UT010009: Servlet remoting of type class org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet does not implement javax.servlet.Servlet"}}
15:04:14,546 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 91) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "myproject.war" was rolled back with the following failure message:
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./myproject.UndertowDeploymentInfoService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./myproject.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: Failed to start service
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UT010009: Servlet remoting of type class org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet does not implement javax.servlet.Servlet"}}

My Web.xml :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
version="2.4" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">  
  <welcome-file-list> 
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file> 
  </welcome-file-list>  
  <context-param> 
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>  
    <param-value>WEB-INF/web-applicationContext.xml</param-value> 
  </context-param>  
  <listener> 
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class> 
  </listener>  
  <listener> 
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class> 
  </listener>  
  <servlet> 
    <servlet-name>remoting</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class> 
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>  
  <servlet-mapping> 
    <servlet-name>remoting</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/remoting/*</url-pattern> 
  </servlet-mapping>
 <servlet>
  <description></description>
  <display-name>ExportReportServlet</display-name>
  <servlet-name>ExportReportServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>ma.hps.powercard.administration.base.serviceimpl.ExportReportServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>ExportReportServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/remoting/ExportReportServlet</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 
</web-app>
```

Comment: maybe any classloading issue?

Comment: Hi Angelo, my war works in Jboss 6.4, but in JBoss EAP 7.0, i've this issue, yes i use the spring 2.5.6. exact in the loading class on my web.xml

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use spring 3.2.+ instead of the spring 2.5.6.
I think Jboss7 is not compatible with spring 2.5.6